# MVC Routing cant seem to get away from default with one paramaeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am relatively new to MVC, done the basis from web tutorials.  I am now in the process of starting an app from scratch, without bastardizing tutorials.

I am trying to map a route, like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DrillDown",
                url: "Home/CupboardDrillDown/{productcat}");
```

However evertime i enter

/home/CupboardDrillDown/1

in my browser i get an error saying that productcat is null, i think that its using the default route, so its passing ID instead of productcat.

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productcat' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using **productcat** in your route then your action parameter must be also named as **productcat**.

please follow an example below

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DrillDown",
            url: "Home/CupboardDrillDown/{productcat}"
  );

public ActionResult CupboardDrillDown(int productcat)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: public ActionResult CupboardDrillDown(int productcat)
        {

            Models.clsProductData PRODDATA = new Models.clsProductData();

            PRODDATA.LEVEL1CATEGORY = productcat;
            return View();

        }    is what i have, Index is already used

Comment: updated the answer. CupboardDrillDown is just an action which you are calling.When you say Home/CupboardDrillDown/24 you are calling CupboardDrillDown action of the HomeController with value of 'productcat' as 24

Comment: Yes, thats what i thought, but it doesnt pass productcat to that controller.

Comment: can you update your question with the action as well. and also let me know if your breakpoint is hitting the action?

Comment: Also make sure your specialized path should be above the generalized path..in other words your map route entry should be above the default routes which is already present

Comment: you are welcome. Why not consider marking this as an answer :)

Comment: there is one more thought which recently came to my mind, why bothering creating a new route..the default route could have worked fro you given that you would have to change the action parameter from 'productcat' to 'id'